# How to Check A PDF reader Is Installed With Java

Tags: java

I Tried to open a pdf file using a statement

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + "Sample.pdf");`.

But I have not installed a `pdf` reader in my system. So it when I execute this program nothing is showing. No Exceptions are comming . Any idea getting the exception if the `Pdf` reader is not installed in the system. If the `Pdf` reader is already installed this program is working perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
As my previous solution was not working . Here is another one that would sure work for you:

```
try
{
  File file = new File("Sample.pdf");
  java.awt.Desktop.getDeskTop().open(file);
  System.out.println("File opened successfully");
}catch(Exception ex)
{
  System.out.println("Error occurred: "+ex);
}
```

Comment: Hi Vishal its not working. It comes inside the if block itself

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to deal with the register key.

Use [JNI](https://github.com/twall/jna) to do the trick.

```
String productName = Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue(
            WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", "ProductName");
        System.out.printf("Product Name: %s\n", productName);
```

[read/write to Windows Registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)

Comment: I have included jna jar.but i cant find Advapi32Util jar file.I have tried windows 7 with 64 bit.is there any other jar needed?